# Why data displayed within dateRange not working in Lollipop device?

Tags: android, date, datetime

Here, start date and end date in between any shopping Time exists then it returns the list of Shopping details with below code.

In Marshmallow device, below code working fine. when same code runs in Lollipop device it is not working. so can anyone guide me what's the issue?

```
public boolean isDetailsWithinRange(Date startDate, Date endDate)
    {
        boolean flag= false;
        Date date = getShoppingTime();
        if (date != null && startDate!= null && endDate != null) {
            if (date.after(startDate) && date.before(endDate)) {
                flag= true;
            }
            else {
                flag= false;
            }
        }
        return flag;

    }


public Date getShoppingTime()
{
    return shoppingTime;
}
```

Comment: what is getShoppingTime() method??

Comment: Please post your getShoppingTime() method

Comment: note that **startDate** is not used in the function

Comment: @Manza yes.. using shiftDate not start date

Comment: so, what is shiftDate ? PS : if-else could basicly be removed by a simpe assignement of `flag`

Comment: I have edited my question again.

Comment: And `ShoppingTime()` ?

Comment: Edited my question.